# Prefactoring to solve many similar linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am designing an algorithm that needs to solve many (large) linear systems of the form $$\Phi^\top D_i\Phi \vec x_i=\vec r_i,$$ where $\Phi\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with $m>n$ is fixed.  We will need to solve this system for many positive diagonal matrices $D_i$.  The product $\Phi^\top D_i\Phi$ is guaranteed to be invertible but obviously $\Phi$ cannot be.

Is there any pre-factorization or manipulation to $\Phi$ that I can do to make this solve as fast as possible for each new $(D,\vec r)$ pair?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still in moderate dimensions, i.e. if a dense $n \times n$ matrix fits into your memory, you can call on a [QR factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of $\Phi$:

$$
\Phi = Q\cdot R = [Q_1,Q_2]\cdot [R_1,0] = Q_1\cdot R_1
$$

with $Q_1 \in \mathbb R^{n\times m}$ unitary, i.e. $Q_1^TQ_1 = I_{n\times n}$, and $R_1 \in \mathbb R^{m\times m}$ upper triangular and invertible.

Then, your coefficient matrix reads $A_1=R_1^TQ_1^TD_iQ_1R_1$ with its inverse given via $A_1^{-1}=R_1^{-1}Q_1^TD_i^{-1}Q_1R_1^{-T}$.

Thus, if you precompute $R_1^{-1}$ and $Q_1$, in every step, you are left with computing $D_1^{-1}$ and

$$
x_i = R_1^{-1}(Q_1^T(D_i^{-1}(Q_1(R_1^{-T}r_i)))).
$$
Note that the brackets restrict the computations to only matrix-vector multiplication.

Comment: To clarify, $\Phi \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $Q_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $R_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.  Moreover, if $m > n$, then $Q_1$ has a left inverse ($Q_1^T Q_1 = {}$ the identity) but not a right inverse ($Q_1 Q_1^T \not= {}$ the identity).  I think this is a critical fact that may have been overlooked... if $m > n$, it means that $\Phi^T D_i \Phi \vec{x}_i = \vec{r}_i$ generally cannot be solved using the proposed QR factorization.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699557/solve-many-linear-systems-of-similar-structure/2699841